# How to write an vertical Histogram

Tags: java

So, right now I managed to output the Histogram like this:

[image: HistogramPic]

The code for this picture is as following:

```java
int max = getBiggest(arr);
int min = getSmallest(arr);
int n = max / 50 + 1;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (int j = min; j < arr[i]; j += n) {
        System.out.print(i + 1);         
    }
    System.out.println("(" + arr[i] + ")");     
}
```

But my task is to output the Histogram like this:

[image: HistogramVertical]

Can someone explain me please how to write this code?

Comment: Try focusing on one row at a time. Can you convert `Integer[] a = {null, 2, 3, null, 5, null}` into that `2 3  5` row? Expand that answer to a list of arrays

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {12, 28, 11, 16, 21, 12};
    int length = arr.length;
    int max = IntStream.of(arr).max().getAsInt();
    int min = IntStream.of(arr).min().getAsInt();
    System.out.println("Histgramm:");
    for (int h = min; h <= max; ++h) {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            System.out.print(arr[i] >= h ? (i + 1) + " " : "  ");
        System.out.println("(" + h + ")");
    }
}
```

output:

```
Histgramm:
1 2 3 4 5 6 (11)
1 2   4 5 6 (12)
  2   4 5   (13)
  2   4 5   (14)
  2   4 5   (15)
  2   4 5   (16)
  2     5   (17)
  2     5   (18)
  2     5   (19)
  2     5   (20)
  2     5   (21)
  2         (22)
  2         (23)
  2         (24)
  2         (25)
  2         (26)
  2         (27)
  2         (28)
```